# Programmatically interact with workflows

Tags: django-viewflow

i want to interact both from the material frontend and from python code with my workflow, in particular with a View.
The workflow works properly with the material frontend, but i have some problem with programmatically interaction.

I am able to assign the view to an user

```
Task.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs['task_id'])[0].activate().assign(self.request.user)
```

but i cannot go ahead with the view.

The view is defined in the workflow like the following:

```
reporting = (
        flow.View(
            viewsets.Reporting,
            task_description='Reporting'
        ).Permission(
            auto_create=True
        ).Next(this.check_operator_accept)
    )
```

The model to which the view refers has 2 fields:

```
 operator_report = CharField(max_length=150)
 operator_accept = BooleanField(default=False)
```

How can i  set those fields and go ahead with the workflow steps?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Django Views are suited to handle user HTTP request.

To represent programming task, that would be called from code use [flow.Function](http://docs.viewflow.io/viewflow_core_node.html#viewflow.nodes.Function)